# Jboss EAP 7.4.1 configuration issues

Tags: java, batch-processing, jboss-eap-7, jberet

I am trying to bring one of the environments EAP 7.0 to EAP7.4.1 and I have managed to migrate one of the environments successfully. However, on one of the environments, as soon as I start EAP after upgrade in the domain mode, the server runs out of memory with the error below:

```
> "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [
>     (\"host\" => \"somehost-server-1\"),
>     (\"server\" => \"server-1\"),
>     (\"core-service\" => \"platform-mbean\"),
>     (\"type\" => \"operating-system\") ]"
```

I have tried to copy the exact configuration as the other environment where EAP is running smoothly and find no difference. I couldn't find any help if I try to find this error, all I can see is that it has something to do with the Monitoring service of Jboss EAP. Can someone help?

Comment: Is your application a batch processing app using jberet? If so, can you give more details as to the jobs, amount of job executions, job repository, etc.

Comment: Yes I do around 21 batch jobs running in the application. I have configured the job repository to use JDBC so it uses my DB. And the amount of job executions vary from 1 to 2600. But there are several batch jobs where the job execution is above 1500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, apparently jberet was internally trying to fetch details about the job executions from the table(JDBC repository). And since there was a lot of rows in that table, the committed heap size would run out.

After I deleted rows from that table, the server looks stable and everything runs smoothly. I wonder how the server handles a large load since it is constantly trying to fetch that data. Is there an alternate to the solution?

Comment: This issue has been fixed in WildFly 25 and latest EAP version (see [WFLY-14946](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-14946)).